# What does <> mean in PicBasic Pro (or similar language)

Tags: operand

I'm trying to understand the line `if variable <> 1 then`.

I'm having a guess, based on a similar question for a different language, that `<>` is an alternative way of saying `!=` which means not equal to.

Am I right in saying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the [PICBASIC PRO™ Compiler Manual](http://melabs.com/resources/pbpmanual/4_0.htm#418), the `<>` comparison operator is equivalent to `!=`.  Think of `<>` as being "less than or greater than" (but not equal to).

Answer (score 0):

*Not equal*. In C-like programming languages this is analog to `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct: the `<>` operator ist in BASIC dialects the way to indicate a `not equal`.